# Evaluate a model entered by user as python function

Tags: string, function, python-3.x, anonymous-function

I have to program a task in python 3.4 that requires the following:
 - The program ask the user to enter a data model that is made by several submodels in a form of string like the following:

```
# the program ask :
please input the submodel1
# user will input:
A = a*x + b*y*exp(3*c/d*x)
# then the program ask :
-> please input the submodel2
# user will input:
B = e*x + f*y*exp(3*h/d*x)
# then the program ask :
-> please input the main model:
# user will input:
Y = A*x - exp(B**2/y)
```

then the program take these models (strings) and performs some operations on them like curve fitting of the main model to existing data and plot results with showing parameters values.
the idea here is to give the user the freedom of choosing the model at runtime without needing to program it as a function inside the app.
my problem here resides in converting or interpreting the string as a python function that returns value. I explored solution like the eval() function but I am looking to a solution that is like in the MatLab

```
func = sym('string')
func = matlabfunction(func)
```

which creates an anonymous function that you can deal with it easily
hope I made myself clear, if any further clarification needed please let me know,
the solution should be compatible with python 3.4
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem by creating a small parser or let's say a very small dsl based on python library PLY, please refer to this web page for details:
http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html#ply_nn1
and to this project:
https://github.com/maldoinc/mamba

Answer (score 0):

you can use parse from:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/parse 
and train your parser to recognize mathematical expressions,
see this example(python27):
http://www.nerdparadise.com/tech/python/parsemath/

```
# A really simple expression evaluator supporting the
# four basic math functions, parentheses, and variables.

class Parser:
    def __init__(self, string, vars={}):
        self.string = string
        self.index = 0
        self.vars = {
            'pi' : 3.141592653589793,
            'e' : 2.718281828459045
            }
        for var in vars.keys():
            if self.vars.get(var) != None:
                raise Exception("Cannot redefine the value of " + var)
            self.vars[var] = vars[var]

    def getValue(self):
        value = self.parseExpression()
        self.skipWhitespace()
        if self.hasNext():
            raise Exception(
                "Unexpected character found: '" +
                self.peek() +
                "' at index " +
                str(self.index))
        return value

    def peek(self):
        return self.string[self.index:self.index + 1]

    def hasNext(self):
        return self.index < len(self.string)

    def skipWhitespace(self):
        while self.hasNext():
            if self.peek() in ' \t\n\r':
                self.index += 1
            else:
                return

    def parseExpression(self):
        return self.parseAddition()

    def parseAddition(self):
        values = [self.parseMultiplication()]
        while True:
            self.skipWhitespace()
            char = self.peek()
            if char == '+':
                self.index += 1
                values.append(self.parseMultiplication())
            elif char == '-':
                self.index += 1
                values.append(-1 * self.parseMultiplication())
            else:
                break
        return sum(values)

    def parseMultiplication(self):
        values = [self.parseParenthesis()]
        while True:
            self.skipWhitespace()
            char = self.peek()
            if char == '*':
                self.index += 1
                values.append(self.parseParenthesis())
            elif char == '/':
                div_index = self.index
                self.index += 1
                denominator = self.parseParenthesis()
                if denominator == 0:
                    raise Exception(
                        "Division by 0 kills baby whales (occured at index " +
                        str(div_index) +
                        ")")
                values.append(1.0 / denominator)
            else:
                break
        value = 1.0
        for factor in values:
            value *= factor
        return value

    def parseParenthesis(self):
        self.skipWhitespace()
        char = self.peek()
        if char == '(':
            self.index += 1
            value = self.parseExpression()
            self.skipWhitespace()
            if self.peek() != ')':
                raise Exception(
                    "No closing parenthesis found at character "
                    + str(self.index))
            self.index += 1
            return value
        else:
            return self.parseNegative()

    def parseNegative(self):
        self.skipWhitespace()
        char = self.peek()
        if char == '-':
            self.index += 1
            return -1 * self.parseParenthesis()
        else:
            return self.parseValue()

    def parseValue(self):
        self.skipWhitespace()
        char = self.peek()
        if char in '0123456789.':
            return self.parseNumber()
        else:
            return self.parseVariable()

    def parseVariable(self):
        self.skipWhitespace()
        var = ''
        while self.hasNext():
            char = self.peek()
            if char.lower() in '_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789':
                var += char
                self.index += 1
            else:
                break

        value = self.vars.get(var, None)
        if value == None:
            raise Exception(
                "Unrecognized variable: '" +
                var +
                "'")
        return float(value)

    def parseNumber(self):
        self.skipWhitespace()
        strValue = ''
        decimal_found = False
        char = ''

        while self.hasNext():
            char = self.peek()            
            if char == '.':
                if decimal_found:
                    raise Exception(
                        "Found an extra period in a number at character " +
                        str(self.index) +
                        ". Are you European?")
                decimal_found = True
                strValue += '.'
            elif char in '0123456789':
                strValue += char
            else:
                break
            self.index += 1

        if len(strValue) == 0:
            if char == '':
                raise Exception("Unexpected end found")
            else:
                raise Exception(
                    "I was expecting to find a number at character " +
                    str(self.index) +
                    " but instead I found a '" +
                    char +
                    "'. What's up with that?")

        return float(strValue)

def evaluate(expression, vars={}):
    try:
        p = Parser(expression, vars)
        value = p.getValue()
    except Exception as (ex):
        msg = ex.message
        raise Exception(msg)

    # Return an integer type if the answer is an integer
    if int(value) == value:
        return int(value)

    # If Python made some silly precision error
    # like x.99999999999996, just return x + 1 as an integer
    epsilon = 0.0000000001
    if int(value + epsilon) != int(value):
        return int(value + epsilon)
    elif int(value - epsilon) != int(value):
        return int(value)

    return value

print evaluate("1 + 2 * 3")
print evaluate("(1 + 2) * 3")
print evaluate("-(1 + 2) * 3")
print evaluate("(1-2)/3.0 + 0.0000")
print evaluate("1 + pi / 4")
print evaluate("(a + b) / c", { 'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3 })
print evaluate("(x + e * 10) / 10", { 'x' : 3 })
print evaluate("1.0 / 3 * 6")
print evaluate("(1 - 1 + -1) * pi")
print evaluate("pi * e")
```

Comment: Thanks very much Hamza, it is this kind of solution I am seeking for, I hope to see more answers before accepting one, anyway this gave me a strong start point thanks

Comment: @hamza hebal Could add text relevant to the answer. If the links were to go away, this answer would not have any value. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

lmfit (http://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/) has an ExpressionModel that you might find useful:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from lmfit.models import ExpressionModel

# make fake data
x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 201)
amp, cen, wid =  3.4, 1.8, 0.5

y = amp * np.exp(-(x-cen)**2 / (2*wid**2)) / (np.sqrt(2*np.pi)*wid)
y += np.random.normal(size=len(x), scale=0.01)

# create model from expression
model= ExpressionModel("amp * exp(-(x-cen)**2 /(2*wid**2))/(sqrt(2*pi)*wid)")

# fit data to that model
result = model.fit(y, x=x, amp=5, cen=5, wid=1)

# show results
print(result.fit_report())
plt.plot(x, y,         'bo')
plt.plot(x, result.init_fit, 'k--')
plt.plot(x, result.best_fit, 'r-')
plt.show()
```

This uses asteval (http://newville.github.io/asteval) and so supports a fairly rich subset of Python syntax and numpy constants and ufuncs, including `sqrt`, `exp`, `sin`, `pi`, and so on.

Comment: Thanks Newville, this is awesome for most of the cases and it worked on many of mine, in my case I should use a customized parser otherwise this will be the best answer, Thanks